# Change packet endianness in Scapy

Tags: python, scapy, packet

I've created a custom layer in Scapy that represents the Little Endian format of a packet.

```
class test_layer(Packet):
    name = "test"
    fields_desc = [
        BitField('A', 0, size=10),
        BitField('B', 0, size=6),
        BitField('C', 0, size=11),
        BitField('D', 0, size=5)
    ]
```

I create a new packet

```
pkt = test_layer(A=1021, B=33, C=816, D=3)
```

which results in a hexdump of `FF 61 66 03`

Before sending the packet I need to do a 16 bit Big Endian swap so I end up with `61 FF 03 66`.

Due to the odd bit sizes of the fields in the layer (10, 6, 11, 5), I can't just re-order the fields. For example if I re-order A, B, C, D to B, A, D, C the hex comes out to 87 FD 1B 30.

Any suggestions for how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you set the size to a negative value, the fields will be in low endian

Comment: thanks for the input once again. I tried to set size to negative number, for example 
BitField('A', 0, size=-10)... but I get the same result.